# Firebase rules don't allow access

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

So my flutter code works fine until I change my Firebase Realtime Database rules. It does not throw an error in debug console or anything, but the app does not get the data. I attach my rules and the login method.

```
"rules": {
 "$uid": {
     ".read": "auth.uid == $uid || auth.request.uid == $uid",
     ".write": "auth.uid == $uid || auth.request.uid == $uid"
   }
}
```

And:

```
void authUser(String email, String password, bool isLogin,
      String username) async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    UserCredential userCreadencial;
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

    try {
      if (isLogin == false) {
        userCreadencial = await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );
      } else {
        userCreadencial = await firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );
      }
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users_info')
          .orderBy(userCreadencial.user!.uid, descending: true);
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users_info')
          .doc(userCreadencial.user!.uid)
          .set({
        'email': userCreadencial.user!.email,
        'username': username,
      });

      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (err) {
      print(err);
      var message = 'An error occurred, pelase check your credentials!';

      if (err.message != null) {
        message = err.message!;
      }

      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text(message),
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
        ),
      );
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your dart code shows that you use the [Firestore database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) but your rules correspond to the [Realtime Database.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) These two different NoSQL Database services offered by Firebase use different security rules syntax.

You should use the [Firestore syntax](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview) and edit your rules in the correct place:

- Either via the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/) through the "Firestore database" vertical menu item, **not** the "Realtime database" vertical menu item
- Or by modifying the correct rules file as configured in the `firebase.json` file of your Firebase project (which is in on your computer), see below.

For a default project config in the `firebase.json` as shown below, you should define the Firestore rules in the `firestore.rules` file.

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  ...
```

Comment: Hi @CaptainCutlet, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?